# auto-generate my xml through out the build process

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, auto-generate

Let's say I have a serialized class (members with attribtues and everything).
Is there a way I can auto-generate it's correlative XML within the build? this will be a required file to be inserted to the msi...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Build Events - you can generate your file in post-build event. Look inside your project properties window.

Comment: @user1025852 - You could edit project file and use AfterBuild MSBuild target.